# How to prove you created it first

Tags: copyright

Let's say you write really good articles and people start copying them. After a while it may not even be clear who did it first.
Now assume the unlikely event that someone registers copyright with your article as if it is theirs, and then come after you. How do you prove that you were the original writer of that article? Don't say your server logs, it belongs to you and you can modify them. And yes copyright registration is definite answer but it is too impractical and expensive. And i am not asking about going after someone here. I am asking if anyone comes after you, with your content. I know this is highly unlikely but wanted to know what steps do you / would you take after writing a good article to protect yourself, to prove that you wrote that article on a certain date. email to yourself? Save it somewhere on web? share on social media? what else?

Comment: I doubt it would be worth my time and effort to do anything. I would forget about it and write better articles.

Comment: Having said the above - before digital I would write comedy sketches and then mail them to myself so that there was a postmark to prove a date.  I wonder if there is a way to do it digitally these days e.g. google docs.  Create the document, never edit it and there should be a "created date".

Comment: Publish the article, then go to Internet Archive and ask it to take a snapshot of the page.  This will provide third party verification and include a time and date.  If you needed to start emailing the article around you probably would want to strike up a deal with a law firm to accept and archive these emails (why a lawyer - because they have a duty to the state - hence Bar exams) - but my guess is that would be expensive both to set up and to use to prove you wrote the articles.

Comment: @davidgo where is internet archive? archive.org?

Comment: Yup. https://archive.org/web/web.php